# BadParcelableException (very rare and random happening) after adding Interface callback into Bundle?

Tags: android, badparcelableexception

I see (not regularly - just very rarely = cca 1 in 1000 times) `BadParcelableException` when trying to retrieve from `Bundle`.

Anybody has any idea why it happens? I thought it should either happen always, or never, not randomly. This is my code:

1. Parcelable object I am putting into Bundle:

   ```
   public interface ButtonPressedCallback extends Parcelable {
       public void onButtonPressed ();
   }
   ```
2. This is how I put it in Bundle

   ```
   bundle.putString(MyFragment.TITLE, title);
   bundle.putParcelable(MyFragment.CALLBACK , callback);
   ```
3. This is how I retrieve it (and here it crashes)

   ```
   public class MyFragment extends Fragment {    
       private String title;
       private ButtonPressedCallback callback;

       public static final String TITLE = "TITLE";
       public static final String CALLBACK = "CALLBACK";

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           Bundle b = getArguments();

           title = getArguments().getString(TITLE); // it crashes here
           callback = b.getParcelable(CALLBACK );
           ...
      }
   ```

It mysteriously crashes on line when retrieving just normal string TITLE (weird....) but I am 100% sure that line is ok and it actually crashes below - because it started when I added interface into Bundle

And here is stacktrace:

```
Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator (Parcel.java:2875)
  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable (Parcel.java:2797)
  at android.os.Parcel.readValue (Parcel.java:2700)
  at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal (Parcel.java:3067)
  at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel (BaseBundle.java:257)
  at android.os.BaseBundle.getString (BaseBundle.java:1086)
       at sk.myapp.intro.MyFragment.onCreate (MyFragment.java:42)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate (Fragment.java:2414)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1418)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1784)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1852)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange (FragmentManagerImpl.java:3269)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate (FragmentManagerImpl.java:3223)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreate (FragmentController.java:190)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java:369)
       at sk.myapp.intro.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:46)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7183)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1221)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2910)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3032)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1696)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6942)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: You should avoid using `Bundle` as there is a limit of 1MB storage & it crashes if it exceeds this limit, instead use `Model` to pass data from one component to other.

Comment: how can it exceed limit 1 MB when I am just passing some simple callback method? Also, do you have any example of usage? THanks

Comment: I faced this issue when i was putting a huge Model(sometimes ArrayList of Model) into bundle using `putParcelable` and was using `setArguments(bundle)` while adding a fragment. Let me check the bundle in your scenario.

Comment: In `bundle.putParcelable(MyFragment.CALLBACK , callback);`, how have u initialized `callback` in your code? what's stored in it?

Comment: see my anaswer below I posted code (it adds widget on screen)

Comment: @Astha do you have any tips? (see my answer below)

Comment: Where is this code `bundle.putString(MyFragment.TITLE, title);
bundle.putParcelable(MyFragment.CALLBACK , callback);` written?

Comment: in one of my classes which is creating fragment

Comment: Is `callback`(in above question) same as `successCallback` (in below answer)?

Comment: no thats different thing. My callback is method containing that code below

Answer (score 1):

Writing this since I couldn't provide example in comment ,

```
@SuppressLint("ParcelCreator")
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CallbackInterface{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("CALLBACK",this); // <---

    }

    @Override
    public void demoCallback() {

    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    }
}
```

Since I'm passing `this`, It may crash when my Activity holds lots of member variables (> 1MB)

Comment: I already solved problem by getting rid of parcelable and just using another callback to my activity. its a bit mroe complicated but I got rid of this exception. Anyway thank you very much for your help and effort, I appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 0):

Astha this is in callback (basically just adding widgte on homescreen through button):

```
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager =
        context.getSystemService(AppWidgetManager.class);
ComponentName myProvider =
        new ComponentName(context, MyAppWidgetProvider.class);

if (appWidgetManager.isRequestPinAppWidgetSupported()) {
    // Create the PendingIntent object only if your app needs to be notified
    // that the user allowed the widget to be pinned. Note that, if the pinning
    // operation fails, your app isn't notified.
    Intent pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent = new Intent( ... );

    // Configure the intent so that your app's broadcast receiver gets
    // the callback successfully. This callback receives the ID of the
    // newly-pinned widget (EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID).
    PendingIntent successCallback = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    appWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget(myProvider, null, successCallback);
}
```